# Why doesn't functions from Array work on 'arguments'?

Tags: javascript

Why can't we directly call the functions from Array on `arguments`?

```
function f(){
   var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
   //var x = arguments.slice(1);  **error**
 alert(x);
}

f(1,2,3);
```

Update:  If `arguments` is not an array object, then how does the Array.prototype.slice function works on an non-array object?

Comment: That will simply copy the members of *arguments* to a new array as if by a simple for loop that iterates over it from 0 to length - 1. Early versions of Opera implemented *arguments* as an array, but that was not compliant with ECMA-262 so it stopped doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, despite having some array-like qualities, the `arguments` object is not an Array.

It is [defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) independently of, and without reference to, [Array objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4).

Comment: So how does the prototype.slice function works on an non-array?

Comment: The same way as it works on an array. It looks at the value of `this` and then manipulates it. The `arguments` object has all the array-like qualities needed by the function. It just doesn't have the function itself.